# Access and MySQL

Tags: mysql, ms-access, vba

I'm using Access 2002 with unbound forms and linked tables to a MySql backend on the internet.   I'm trying to update a table using this code but it wont update.  Any help appreciated. Thanks.

```
Dim PhoneSQL As String
DoCmd.SetWarnings False
MySql(Connect,"uclock.db.7713143.hostedresource.com,urlock,Admin33334)
PhoneSQL = "UPDATE tblClients SET tblClients.MainPhone = `enter code here`Forms!frmEditAddress!TxtPhone " & _
"WHERE tblClient.ClientID = Forms!frmEditPhone!TxtClientID;"
DoCmd.RunSQL (PhoneSQL)
DoCmd.SetWarnings True
mySql(close)
```

Comment: DSTR3 you need to provide more details before people will help.

Comment: Any particular reason for using unbound forms ? Linking the tables would make your life easier !

Comment: I figured the "over the Internet" part of it was a pretty good reason for not using bound forms.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a closing quote here:

```
 MySql(Connect,"uclock.db.7713143.hostedresource.com,urlock,Admin33334)
                                             -----------------------^^^^
```

The syntax highlighter betrays the error.  Hopefully you are working in an IDE or text editor with proper syntax highlighting for VBA.

Other issues seen:

Improper quoting around the form value in `PhoneSQL`

```
PhoneSQL = "UPDATE tblClients SET tblClients.MainPhone = `enter code here`Forms!frmEditAddress!TxtPhone " & _
"WHERE tblClient.ClientID = Forms!frmEditPhone!TxtClientID;"
```

Should be

```
PhoneSQL = "UPDATE tblClients SET tblClients.MainPhone = `enter code here`Forms!frmEditAddress!TxtPhone " & _
"WHERE tblClient.ClientID = " & Forms!frmEditPhone!TxtClientID & ";"
```

And there is no `MySQL()` function.  Since your tables are linked, you do not need to make any new database connection.

Comment: Thank you.  That help.  However, I think more is missing.  It still wont UPDATE.  Its saying function isn't defined?

Comment: @DSTR3 what is the function `MySQL()`? That isn't like anything I have ever seen to connect to a database in VBA

Comment: I'm using that in C++ so I just thought I would try it! Wrong I guess!  In any case, I have these unbound forms with SQL statements ready to go, my tables are linked and I am able to update directly in the table so my connection is good.  Is there something that I must do since I have unbound forms?  What is the correct process or syntax?  Have been looking for two days now!

Comment: If your tables are linked you don't need to perform any connection.  There is some incorrect quoting here `"WHERE tblClient.ClientID = Forms!frmEditPhone!TxtClientID;"` I think you need `"WHERE tblClient.ClientID = " & Forms!frmEditPhone!TxtClientID & ";"`

Comment: Thank you so much.  That's where the confusion was.  I corrected the statement. But the biggie was I thought I had to make a connection since my forms are unbound.  But I don't! Thank you!